# click vs on click for incoming element

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(function(){
    $('div').append('<a>link</a>');

  $('a').click(function(){
    alert('trigger <a>!');
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nj6Lsgo1/

Why does the `<a>` trigger in my case? I thought I have to use binding like `.on()` for incoming elements.

Comment: The order of the script is the reason... before the `click` handler is added you are adding the `anchor` element to dom... if you move the `append()` to after the `click` then it won't work - https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/n173pqwf/1/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/n173pqwf/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does the `<a>` trigger in my case?

The event is simply being triggered because you are attaching the `click` event listener *after* appending the anchor element to the DOM.

In other words, `$('a').click(function() {...});` will attach the `click` event listener to all `a` elements that exist in the DOM at that time.

Since the `a` element has already been appended, the `click` event listener is attached.

> I thought I have to use binding like `.on()` for incoming elements

You only need to [delegate the event listener](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) if you are attaching an event listener *before* the element exists in the DOM.

For instance, if you were to reverse the logic and append the element directly *after* attaching the event listener, it simply wouldn't work:

```
// This wouldn't be fired since the element is 
// appended after the event listener is attached

$('a').click(function() {
  alert('trigger <a>!');
});

$('div').append('<a>link</a>');
```

Which is why you would need to delegate the event listener to an ancestor element that does exist in the DOM at that time:

```
$('div').on('click', 'a', function() {
  alert('trigger <a>!');
});

$('div').append('<a>link</a>');
```

Comment: ya exactly the a is coming before the click listening, no?